# How can one declare an array's each size separately in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

Consider the following array:

```
private int[][] Blocks;
```

How can I specify each of this array's sizes separately? 
Something like so was my first idea: (throws an error though)

```
Blocks = new int[5][];
Blocks = new int[][7];
```

Errors come as following:

- Wrong number of indices inside []; expected 1
- Array creation must have array size or array initializer
- Invalid rank specifier ',' or ']'

Comment: Do a Google Search for "Jagged Arrays in C#"

Comment: You may also consider `List<List<Blocks>>`

Comment: The thing is that I am not totally sure about the order of the declaration of the sizes of the arrays and so, most of the articles out there come up with no use.

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, you may also consider ditching all that and putting the row/column data in a proper class, and then doing a simple `List<Block>` and using LINQ to traverse it.

Comment: Why do you even want to split that up into separate statements? You can’t use the array before it’s initialized anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of declaring arrays in two dimensions.

1. True 2-dimensional arrays
2. Jagged arrays

---

A **two dimensional** array is one single array with two dimensions, i.e. one matrix. It has a rectangular shape:

```
int[,] twoDimensionalArray = new int[5, 7];
```

You can loop through all elements of a two dimensional array like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < twoDimensionalArray.GetLength(0); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < twoDimensionalArray.GetLength(1); j++) {
        int element = twoDimensionalArray[i, j];
        // TODO: Do something with element.
    }
}
```

If the array is of constant size, declare constants for the size:

```
const int ArrWidth = 5, ArrHeight = 7;

int[,] twoDimensionalArray = new int[ArrWidth, ArrHeight];

for (int i = 0; i < ArrWidth; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ArrHeight; j++) {
        int element = twoDimensionalArray[i, j];
        // TODO: Do something with element.
    }
}
```

You can also enumerate all elements of a multi-dimensional array as a flattened enumeration with `foreach`:

```
foreach (int element in twoDimensionalArray) {
    // TODO: Do something with element.
}
```

---

A **jagged array** is an array of arrays. You must create the array in two steps:

```
// First create the base (or outer) array
int[][] jaggedArray = new int[5][];

// Then create the nested (or innner) arrays
jaggedArray[0] = new int[7];
jaggedArray[1] = new int[2];
jaggedArray[2] = new int[11];
jaggedArray[3] = new int[0];
jaggedArray[4] = new int[4];
```

Because the nested arrays can have different sizes, this type of array is called "jagged".

You can loop through all elements of a jagged array like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jaggedArray.Length; i++) {
    int[] inner = jaggedArray[i];
    if (inner != null) {
        for (int j = 0; j < inner.Length; j++) {
            int element = inner[j];
            // TODO: Do something with element.
        }
    }
}
```

You can leave out the null-test, if you know that you have initialized all inner arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
int[][] blocks = ...
```

is an array of arrays.

what you want probably, is a 2-dimensional array, which is declared like this:

```
int[,] blocks = new int[5,7];
```

---

If you really want an array of arrays, you can only declare the first 'dimension' like this:

```
int[][] block = new int[5][];
```

This creates an array of 5 (nulls).

Now you have to create each of those 'subarrays' like this:

```
block[0] = new int[3];
block[1] = new int [20];
```

The dieffernece here is, that each "subarray" can have a totally different size, compared to the 2-dimensional array.

Comment: But he clearly *doesn't* want this, as he wants to be able to initialize one dimension without another.

Answer (score 0):

what do you declare is an array of arrays so  you have two cases.

```
Blocks = new int[5][];
```

the first is the size of the content of the array have same dimension

```
for (int i = 0; i < Blocks.Length; i++)
    Blocks[i] = new int[8];
```

the second is the size of the content of the array have different dimension:

```
Blocks[0] = new int[6];
Blocks[1] = new int[4];
Blocks[2] = new int[10];
Blocks[3] = new int[7];
Blocks[4] = new int[3];
```